# Android TtsService.apk?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis):**Version 1.6 of Android added support for speech synthesis (TTS)**.
But my question is "Does any Android device has TtsService.apk"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 1.6+ has a built-in TTS service on every device (short of, maybe, some extreme customizations). For extended TTS services - i. e. the ability to use plug-in third party engines - one has to download the free "TTS Services Extended" app from the Market.

On Android 2.2 and above - the majority of the current installed base - the extended TTS service is baked in.

The specific APK name is irrelevant, it's an implementation detail.

EDIT:
1 . Quoting http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html :

> Starting with Android 1.6 (API Level 4), the Android platform includes a new Text-to-Speech (TTS) capability.

2 . What do you mean by "TTS (files)"? The standard engine on Android 1.5 and below? The extended TTS service? Some third party engine? Your own engine?

Comment: ,there are two questions remain:1-Can you represent documentation for your answer?2-Do you know any way to install TTS (files) on device by my App?

Comment: ,thank you for your reference and your answer.I saw some devices with android 2.3.* that they have not TTS files(some .bin files that usually are in mnt/sdcard/svox).Without them,device can not use it's TTS engine.Now I solve this problem:I set zipped TTS files in  raw folder of my project and extract them to path that is root directory of TTS engine of device.